# PAM - Disabling "check pass; user unknown" syslog messages

Tags: logs, sshd, pam, authentication, syslog

**TLDR:** We use PAM with SSHD. CentOS and Ubuntu exist in the environment. For every SSHD failure of an **unknown user**, it creates two messages. One of the messages doesn't provide the unknown username and junks up our SIEM. I want to cull the messages at the source vs. drop them at the SIEM. I still want other PAM auth messages, for now.

With that said, I'm trying to figure out how to get the following PAM message silenced since its redundant to another PAM message. It's also possible all of the lower-level PAM messages are redundant to higher-level sshd syslog messages, but I want to at least silence the useless PAM message first before doing additional tuning.

Useless PAM message:

```
    sshd[] pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
```

The above is redundant to the following more verbose message (which is sent near instantaneously):

```
sshd[] pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user <user>: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
```

I believe both of these may also be redundant to this higher-level message generated by sshd itself:

```
sshd[] error: PAM: User not known to the underlying authentication module for illegal user <user> from <ip>
```

I tried digging through several man pages on PAM to understand how the different files link together.

Based on the syslog message, I believe this has to do with the PAM auth module, so looking in the password-auth-ac file (linked by the pass-auth SL), we have the following:

```
auth required pam_env.so
auth required pam_faildelay.so delay=20000000
auth [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_succeed_if.so uid >=1000 quiet
auth [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth sufficient pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth required pam_deny.so
```

If my assumptions above are correct, I would have thought the line that would trigger the check pass; unknown user message would have been line 4: pam_localuser.so. However that line instructs us to ignore the results of that, so my next thought is that it may actually be generated on the line: auth sufficient pam_unix.so line or the pam_sss line, since they're referenced by the syslog entries. I read the man page and modified the file to feed that line the quiet argument, but that didn't work.

The control-flag **sufficient** equals *[success=done new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]*, which if I understand right, the *default=ignore* should also cause this syslog to be ignored. I'm guessing at this point its not actually generated on that line either and I'm a bit confused on where to look next.

A few questions surrounding this:

1. Am I even looking at the right file to attempt to stop the logging?
   If yes, what am I misunderstanding on how to quiet the "check pass;
   user unknown" message?
2. If I want to more aggressively disable syslog generated from PAM for
   SSHD, what's the best way to accomplish that?
3. If I wanted to take it even further and disable all syslog generated
   from PAM, what's the best way to do that? (I'd like to turn it off
   in PAM vs. modify rsyslog filtering on what to forward to the syslog
   server.)
4. Lastly, assuming that I want to make a change for one of the options
   above, what's the best way to create a persistent change? The file
   warns it is auto-generated, but I'm not entirely sure how I'd make
   these types of changes using the authconfig command.

TIA. If this was covered somewhere else, just point me that way. I did do a bit of looking around here and Reddit before posting this, but I didn't see anything along the lines of what exactly I'm trying to do and clearly, I couldn't piece it all together the man pages well enough.

Comment: Apparently one cannot silence the individual PAM messages, atleast easily.

I'm partially where I wanted to get to by setting the SSHD config's LogLevel to QUIET.

Instead of one 8 syslogs for one failed authentication for an unknown user, I'm down to two. I still have an issue where unknown user's usernames are not written to the syslog.  I still need to figure out how to fix that, if possible.